# CSS3 Reset applying mystery space to first <li>

Tags: css, html-lists, reset

I have a frustrating issue I can't seem to resolve - help/advice would be very much appreciated

I've applied a CSS reset with a margin of 0.

I then need to change a primary nav to display block with an @media query. The nav list displays fine except the first li which has a mystery 25px of margin applied. When I remove margin from my CSS reset the li margin snaps back in to line, however the other content across the site is affected by having no reset for margin present. I've tried to use a first-child and first-of-kind pseudo selector for the first li but with no luck.

I can't post an image to show the issue since I'm a new member...

Comment: Can you post a link to an example image?

Comment: Hi - please see link below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2qSc5WIWe1KLVVxYjgtX2JYT00/view?usp=sharing